# Recently viewed products - Order by viewed

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am using the plugin code linked below. But the order of the loop is random.

https://www.wpexplorer.com/woocommerce-recently-viewed-products-shortcode/

Ideally, products will be listed by the order in which they were viewed for each individual visitor.

How do you change the order so that the last viewed product is first?

Comment: You'd have to sort the query results ('the loop' bit) into the same order as $viewed_products, assuming that's the right order. The order is being lost in the database.

Comment: So should this work:
'orderby'        => $viewed_products

Comment: No, sorry. If you wanted to do the ordering in the database then you'll have to put $viewed_products into a temporary table with an index and replace the 'in' clause with a join to the temporary table. You could then order on the index of the temporary table.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not a competent enough developer to do this.